# How I can fix the indentatioin issue for the first term when printing glossary in latex

Tags: latex

I have problem with my thesis's glossary. I do not understand why the acronym 1G is always indented in this case:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ApSC.png]

Here's my code:

```
\usepackage[acronym, nopostdot,abbreviations, style=super, nonumberlist, toc, stylemods,symbols]{glossaries}

\setglossarystyle{long}
\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textbf{#1}}

\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\include{header.tex} %header is file of acronyms, glossary


\lhead{\emph{List of Tables}}  % Set the left side page header to "List of Tables"
\listoftables  % Write out the List of Tables
%\clearpage
%
\lhead{\emph{Abbreviations}}
%\printacronyms[style=\Gls, title=Abbreviations, nonumberlist, sort=standard]
\singlespacing
%\printindex
\makeglossaries
\printglossary[title={List of Abbreviations}]
\doublespacing

\end{document}
```

I do not want to usepackage `{glossaries-extra}` because it will not display the definition of the glossary in the text.

Comment: Can you update your code to include a few glossary entries instead of the `\include{header.tex}` command? It's easier to help you if we can just run your code and see what's happening.

Comment: Hi, I've tried to reproduce your issue. For the sake of completeness, what `documentclass` are you using?  Also, is it possible that you have forgotten to mention all packages (all `\usepackage` commands)? E.g. I wonder if `\usepackage{fancyhdr}` isn't supposed to be there as well, since I got `undefined control sequence 'lhead'`.